# Multipler and Constant in ConstraintWithItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know what this multiplier and constant stands in constraintWithItem which we use in setting auto layout using coding?

Code:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                          toItem:self.view
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    multiplier:0.5
    constant:0]
```

Comment: check this doc....https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/

Comment: hope that my answer will clarify it to you, if still unclear, feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation would be like this:

`newValue = oldValue * multiplier + constant`

The new value in this case would be calculated value for the attribute you specified for the view which is passed as a first argument, the old value is the second view's value of the specified attribute. If you pass `NSLayoutAttributeNone` then the multiplier argument will have no effect only constant will be taken into account (so in this way you could specify width or height for some view for example but not only).

[Good reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:)

If mine explanation is confusing then from the Apple's reference you might find below part especially explanatory (and precise):

> Constraints represent linear equations of the form view1.attr1  multiplier × view2.attr2 + c. If the constraint you wish to express does not have a second view and attribute, use nil and NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute.

As a real life example that method can be used in cases like:

1. I want this view to be twice wider than this one
2. I want this view's attribute to have that value
3. many more :)